# Pass Json img src to front-end

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am able to select multiple images on the back-end of WordPress and list on the Json format at the console. 
However I can't manage to show and display them on the front-end, how do I parse the format ?

```
(...)
const imagesList = img.map( ( img ) => {
  return {
     imgID: img.url,
  };
});

props.setAttributes({
  imgURL: JSON.stringify( imagesList )
});
(...)
```

Comment: By front end you mean in Gutenberg view or in actual front end?

Comment: Both, but first in Gutenberg's view and save the data to show on the front end.